# A simple usb controlled switch

Tags: usb

I'm not really a hardware guy but I am thinking that this might be a simple build. With some guidance.

Basically I want to hook a physical button switch to a controlled one for my camera. So that I could say make a program that will release the shutter every minute or something simple like that.

The switch itself is simple. [image: http://www.instructables.com/id/Homebew-Wired-SONY-ALPHA-Remote/step3/Solder-everything-together-inside-of-your-enclsure/]

However how would I hook it up to a usb controller. From reading I think I need a relay but relays seem more complicated. Is this a simple project, or a complicated one? The switch that is controlled should probably not transport any electricity to the wires shown in the picture.

[Source for Image](http://www.instructables.com/id/Homebew-Wired-SONY-ALPHA-Remote/step3/Solder-everything-together-inside-of-your-enclsure/)

Comment: We're going to need more detail about the meaning of "a USB controller" - does that mean a computer, or something like a game joystick?  But given that this is a migrated question, please exercise a little patience in waiting for that detail to be provided.

Comment: I'm assuming he wants a usb gpio device. Probably with two optocouplers or fet/transistors. @ChrisStratton

Comment: @Mallow depending on the camera, it might already have usb control available. Also, do you neeeeed a computer to be involved? A `intervalometer` can be made with off the shelf parts (555 timer + resistors/caps/transistor) or a microcontroller and give you the same thing, without a need for a laptop or computer nearby.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a computer, All I want is a timer to set off the shutter every some odd seconds. But judging from the replies it seems really complicated, even doing it via serial bus. @ChrisStratton

Comment: @PasserBy well a quick ebay search on intervalometer, and I think it already exists for my camera... I guess this might not be the best electronic project for a beginner.

Comment: It's not clear why USB is involved in your project.  Is your camera designed to be controlled over USB?  Are you looking to have a button you can push, or some sort of automatic interval trigger?

Comment: @Mallow, it really isn't complicated, in either way. A simple intervalometer can be used, a microcontroller, or a usb driven device. Even for a beginner. All you are doing is grounding two pins to a third. USB adds an extra layer that you would need to make an app to control it, but even then. The biggest thing though, is that some cameras already have usb control. For example, Most Canon Powershot cameras can use a PTP protocol, and I can take pictures from my Mac's builtin Photo Importer software. No need for any extra hardware.

Comment: @ChrisStratton the usb is not important it's just so that I could code something like for i = 1 to 100 wait 5 seconds push camera trigger next i

Comment: @Passerby It seems my camera is considered "Consumer Grade" and It doesn't have that feature. (At least not that I know of) [It's a Sony Alpha 350]

Comment: @Mallow It does have USB PTP mode, instead of USB mass storage mode, and that might give you a way to take pictures. With a mac, you can just use `Image Capture` to `Take Picture` once the camera in PTP mode. On a PC, well, the builtin camera/scanner function might do the same, or you might find a third party application, I'm not aware of one personally.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be that complicated.  Get an [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/) and 2 NPN transistors.  Connect it up like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4AYxx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can either write the Arduino program to work standalone, or to listen for commands sent over USB.  Either way, you set one of the GPIOs high to start autofocus, and the other high to snap the photo.  If you want to get fancy, google for "arduino intervalometer" and there are a bazillion projects to choose from.

Comment: I've built this exact circuit for this exact purpose (controlling an Canon DSLR using the remote jack) and can verify that it works perfectly.

Comment: You absolutely need resistors on the bases of those transistors.

Answer (score 0):

This should really be asked in the [electronics site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

But anyway - interfacing directly to USB is difficult to say the least. There's a trick you can use to make it easier though. You can pick up a USB-serial bridge for next to nothing on eBay. Windows will then automatically recognise this as a serial port. Writing to a serial port is easy in any language. Also, interfacing hardware to a serial port is relatively easy.

To interface with the serial interface, there are two options.

**Option 1:**

First, your hardware will need a shift register IC and supporting circuitry. So each time you send a byte to the serial port, you can 'hold' onto one of the bits in that byte. This 'bit' will be the one you use to control your signal.

The shift register circuitry will consist of:

- Shift register IC
- Clock signal that triggers the shift register at the baud rate. This could be made with a couple of resistors, a capacitor and schmitt trigger IC.
- Counter circuitry which detects when a byte is finished so it can latch the bits to the output latches.
- Reset circuitry which detects when a byte is not being sent. (When there has been no 'start bit' for at least 8 or 9 bits. This is used to initialise the hardware so it can synchronise with the bits being output. It would reset the counter to zero.

Then the next part of the circuitry:

You can't drive a relay directly from the above pin, you'll need something to amplify it. A single transistor should do the trick (either NPN or PNP would be fine). You'll also need a resistor.

The output from that transistor circuit can either be used to drive the relay. It may be possible to omit the relay, but it's probably better to use a relay so it electrically isolates the camera circuitry from the USB circuitry.

So this is probably not a good project for a non-hardware person! While it's not difficult, there would be a chunk of learning involved. The circuit would be very forgiving though, there wouldn't be any tight tolerances with timing, noise etc.

**Option 2:**

Use a microprocessor like one of the low-end PIC microprocessors that have a UART. (Universal Asynchronous Receiver/Transmitter). You will need a programmer for this, they can be picked up new on eBay for about $30. It should be quite easy to find sample code online which latches the serial data onto the pins. This is probably the best option for you, as you may not have to alter a single line of code. The PIC microprocessors have everything you need except for the output stage (See NPN/PNP/Relay above).